# Is there any command line code which can help me verify passwords for files within zip files?

Tags: shell, command-line

I have about 200 zip files and I need to verify the password for each of the zip files. Is there any command line code which can help me verify passwords for files within these zip files?

Comment: Are you trying to unzip the files? or just verify?  Is the password the same for all of the zip files?

Comment: I am just trying to verify and the password is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
pass="testpassword"
for arch in *.zip; do
  unzip -P $pass -qq -t "$arch" && echo "Pass $pass for $arch"
done
```